# Json generic object type

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'd like to define an object something like this, to map to something like a java Map (but not exactly, since this needs to interface with typescript as well).  Ultimately, what I'm trying to figure out is how to declare the `<T>` type of something (say `Dict<MyObj>`) in another object (if this is even possible):

(this is obviously not a valid json schema)

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "javaType": "some.package.base.DictKeyValuePair",
    "properties": {
        "key": { "type": "string" },
        "value": { "type": "<T>" }
    }
}
```

which would be referenced in other json schemas something like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "javaType": "some.package.base.Dict",
    "properties": {
        "key": { "type": "string" },
        "value": { "type": "<T>" },
        "keValuePairs": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "$ref": "DictKeyValuePair.json",
                "genericType": "<T>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

finally being used in an object similar to this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "javaType": "some.package.SomeObject",
    "properties": {
        "someDict": {
            "$ref": "Dict.json",
            "genericType": "SomeObjectOrSimpleType"
        }
    }
}
```

So... is this possible in a json schema?

Comment: Need to solve this exact issue, represent a Dictionary<T> and Tuple<T, T>.  Can you share any lessons learned?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do something like that using json-schema but you need to define the schemas, take a look to this samples:

http://json-schema.org/learn/examples/address.schema.json

```
{
    "$id":"https://example.com/address.schema.json",
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "description":"An address similar to http://microformats.org/wiki/h-card",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "post-office-box":{
            "type":"string"
        },
        "extended-address":{
            "type":"string"
        },
        "street-address":{
            "type":"string"
        },
        "locality":{
            "type":"string"
        },
        "region":{
            "type":"string"
        },
        "postal-code":{
            "type":"string"
        },
        "country-name":{
            "type":"string"
        }
    },
    "required":[
        "locality",
        "region",
        "country-name"
    ],
    "dependencies":{
        "post-office-box":[
            "street-address"
        ],
        "extended-address":[
            "street-address"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not obvious from your link how to address the notion of generics in json-schema. Also, since links can easily disappear, maybe you can show a brief example of how to use the content your link points to to answer the question more directly. Even quoting a relevant section would be helpful.

Comment: The link has successfully disappeared, as per @rob3c

Comment: This answer shows a good example of a type definition, but that type is not generic (i.e. it doesn't have any type variable) as requested in the question.